# Selecting for morphological components that do not border the edges of an image?

Tags: image-processing

Is there an easy way to select for morphological components which do not border/touch the edges of an image?

Taking this doodle as an example:

[image]

We'd want to only select morphological components that stay at least some critical distance from the edges of the image.

Comment: For example, after labeling all connected components you can check pixels on the border and mark objects that you meet as unlabeled

Comment: Are the morphological components you have in mind the same as the ones shown by `MorphologicalComponents[yourimage] // Colorize`?

Comment: How about adding a border to the picture and then removing the border component (with everything attached to it)?

Comment: How about `DeleteBorderComponents[yourimage]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, MorphologicalComponents[yourimage] // Colorize is perfectly fine - any way you'd like to the select the components.  My interest here is in the filter.

Comment: @MichaelE2 DeleteBorderComponents[yourimage] works.  Sorry, I should have caught that myself.  I can accept your comment as an answer, or I can delete the question?

Comment: @MichaelE2 hit the nail on the head, imho.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Yes he did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DeleteBorderComponents` does what you ask.  You can crop or pad the border, I suppose, if you wish to delete components that are close to the border.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fQ3j.png"];
DeleteBorderComponents[img]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]